# How Can I Make Clothes for a .VRM Model in Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

I want to make some outfits and costumes for my VRoid Studio Model in Blender, but there aren't that many **good** tutorials on YouTube on how to make Anime/VTuber style clothes and I don't want to use the boring default clothes templates in VRoid Studio.

I don't know much about Blender, **but!** I am willing to look up some general tutorials and learn from them to get an idea of what to do. I prefer to learn from video tutorials, than text-based ones.

But since I don't have a lot of options in the video department, I don't know what else to do but ask for help here. I'm more of a 2D Artist than a 3D one, so any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for anime looking clothes, your best bet is to look up "low poly" clothing tutorials. A lot of the look of vtuber type clothes is in the textures though.

The first thing you should familiarize yourself with is learning how to shape the clothes in general. Here's a very basic tutorial on creating clothing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szEeu6_b4fg

After that, you need to learn about UV mapping. You can practice texture creation with the pre-made vroid clothes and whatever drawing program of your choosing, but when creating clothes entirely yourself you'll also need to be able to properly UV map them with the textures. Here's a tutorial I found very useful as I'm kind of new to uv mapping myself.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMRXGscbF5I

If you're having trouble with inspiration, or the mapping and textures, you can always start out with editing MMD clothing that allows editing, as they are similar to the style you're looking for. I find that working "backwards" with this stuff [by breaking things down and seeing how they work, and editing pre-made objects] often helps beginners learn easier, myself included.